# How to use apollo client on Server Side on Next.js 13

Tags: next.js, apollo-client

I am new to next.js and apollo so I created an apollo client.

```
import {
  ApolloClient,
  InMemoryCache,
  HttpLink,
  from,
  split,
} from "@apollo/client";
import { setContext } from "@apollo/client/link/context";
import { WebSocketLink } from "@apollo/client/link/ws";
import { getMainDefinition } from "@apollo/client/utilities";

const httpLink1 = new HttpLink({
  uri: `https://${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_LOCAL_URL1}/graphql`,
});
const httpLink2 = new HttpLink({
  uri: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_LOCAL_URL2}/api/graphql`,
});
const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: `wss://${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_LOCAL_URL3}/graphql`,
  options: {
    reconnect: true,
  },
});

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  const token = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TOKEN}`;
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
    },
  };
});

const httpLinkAuth1 = authLink.concat(httpLink1);
const httpLinkAuth2 = authLink.concat(httpLink2);

const terminatingLink = split(
  ({ query }) => {
    const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
    return (
      definition.kind === "OperationDefinition" &&
      definition.operation === "subscription"
    );
  },
  wsLink,
  from([
    (operation, forward) => {
      const { endpoint } = operation.getContext();
      if (endpoint === "external") {
        return httpLinkAuth1.request(operation, forward);
      } else {
        return httpLinkAuth2.request(operation, forward);
      }
    },
  ])
);

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: terminatingLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

export default apolloClient;
```

but this Appolo clint is only able to access the NEXT_PUBLIC environment variable because I think it is working on client side.

this is my layout file.

```
"use client";

import "./globals.css";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";
import apolloClient from "@/config/apollo";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });


export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
      <html lang="en">
        <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
      </html>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}
```

and in my components I am using "use client" because my component is using useState as well as I am using useMutaion to update the data in Db and also using URL to get data which using authentication.

how can I implement such component in next.js 13 and able to use env variables in apollo client.